# Incrementing both the start and end boundaries of an index in a loop

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, increment

I'm still really new to Python..

I'm trying to produce a while loop that generates successive chunks of a text. This is what I tried:

```py
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

start = 0
i = start
while i < 20:
    for i in range(start, len(alpha)):
        i += 1

        text = alpha[start:i]
        print(text)

        reset = i > 4

        if reset:
            print('reset')
            start += 1
            i = (start)
```

This outputs:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
reset
bcdef
reset
etc....
```

But what I want it to do is:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
reset
b
bc
bcd
bcde
bcdef
reset
c
cd
cde
etc...
```

To me it seems like the bit where I assign `i = start` isn't "working" the way I want it to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why a while loop?  Also think about the value of i.

Comment: FYI: [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) = `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

start = n = 0

while n < len(alpha):
    n += 1

    text = alpha[start:n]
    print(text)

    reset = len(text) > 4

    if reset:
        print('reset')
        start += 1
        n = start
```

Comment: Thank you! Why did you pick 20 for i < 20?

Comment: That's what you had in your question, I'll update it

Comment: Actually what was the version you had with two loops? I think a situation where I have a "for i in range ... " loop nested inside the "while n < len(alpha)" loop would work better for my program.

Comment: Actually, the two while loops were completely redundant.  The answer was the same only the while loop in the answer was encompassed by ```while i < len(alpha):```.  Although two loops in this instance is unnecessary.  You could possibly add a break statement if n (or start) reaches a certain number if you wanted to stop the loop at a certain point (for example `if start == len(alpha) - 5: break` (this would ensure you don't begun another iteration when there are less than five characters to be printed) .  The two while loops above exit at the exact same criteria and thus are redundant.

Comment: is the 'i' in your solution now redundant? because you don't use it anywhere else.

Comment: yes it is, I'll remove it.  We can also simply assign both start and n like such `start = n = 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213968/discussion-between-rexovas-and-kai).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for i in range(20):
    for j in range(1,6):
        text = alpha[i:i+j]
        print(text)
    print("reset")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. Why did you make the upper boundary of the j range 6?

Comment: Because range(1,6) = [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

```
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
count = 0
start = 0
i = 0
while i < 20:
    for j in range(start, len(alpha)):
        count +=1
        text = alpha[start:j]
        print(text)

        reset = count > 5

        if reset:
            print('reset', end='')
            start += 1
            i = start
            count = 0
            break
```

Pretty sure everyone already answered hhaa but did the answer so posting it.